# What would block.coinbase refer to after ethereum transition to POS?

Tags: solidity, mining, proof-of-stake, coinbase, eth-2.0

What would be solidity's `block.coinbase` usage (and what does it refer to) after Ethereum's transition to proof of stake? (formerly known as eth 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post PoS, the execution client (i.e geth) needs a consensus client to run (ex, LightHouse) and they both communicate via the `Engine API` using a local RPC connection. More details [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/merge).

Coming to the question, the consensus client sends a `payload` parameter to the execution client which contains the `suggestedFeeRecipient` parameter, potentially set to the validator's address. The execution client can choose to use this address if it's a honest client or use a different address when it builds the `ExecutionPayload` parameter. The `ExecutionPayload` object will have the traditional block parameters available to use in EVM, contract execution.

More on Engine API : [Engine API](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-apis/blob/main/src/engine/specification.md#engine-api)

More on Consensus client passing the `payload` : [Payload](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-apis/blob/main/src/engine/specification.md#payload-building)

More on Execution client building the `ExecutionPayload` : [ExecutionPayload](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/bellatrix/beacon-chain.md#executionpayload)

Answer (score 1):

`block.coinbase` would have the same usage as it did in PoW, and it still refers to the address that receives the rewards and fees for producing the block.

@Pranay explains how it gets set.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this has nothing to do with "coinbase dot com"

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone The term "coinbase" didn't derive from "coinbase dot com" and it's the other way around: according to Wikipedia, "The company is named after coinbase transactions, which are special transactions that introduce cryptocurrency into circulation in proof of work cryptocurrencies."